# jQuery: Class not added on first click but works on subsequent clicks

Tags: jquery, cookies, click

I'm trying to toggle the `light-mode` CSS class when `#lights` is clicked, and I want to store this change to a cookie. Below is what I've got so far, however it requires the user to click twice for it to work correctly:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($.cookie('light-mode') == "yes") {
        $("body").addClass("light-mode");
    }
    $("#lights").click(function() {
        if ($.cookie('light-mode') == "undefined" || $.cookie('light-mode') == "no") {
            $.cookie('light-mode', 'yes', {
                path: '/'
            });
            $("body").addClass("light-mode");
        } else {
            $.cookie('light-mode', 'no', {
                path: '/'
            });
            $("body").removeClass("light-mode");
        }
    });
});
```

Unless I'm overlooking something simple, the issue might be related to the logic of how I'm using a cookie.

Comment: What is the desired behavior when light-mode cookie value is "no" on first click? (this scenario is missing from your conditional block). When you load your page and cookie('light-mode') exists with a 'no' value, no class is added. I find it strange that subsequent clicks work at all unless there is another function adding your light-mode class to your #lights element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could revise your approach to decouple toggling of the `light-mode` class, and persistence of state to the corresponding cookie like so?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    if ($.cookie('light-mode') == "yes") {
        $("body").addClass("light-mode");
    }
    
    $("#lights").click(function() {
    
      /* Toggle the class regardless of cookie state */
      $("body").toggleClass("light-mode");
      
      /* Update cookie value based on current class assignment */
      $.cookie('light-mode', $("body").hasClass("light-mode") ? 'yes' : 'no', { path: '/' });
    });
});
```